# xmlstarlet.exe not matching XPaths (file with Namespace)

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an example xml file as below.

I've read and followed other questions regarding xmlstarlet and selection from xml files which include namespaces, but just haven't been able to see where my syntax is wrong.

I expect the following to work: 
xmlstarlet.exe sel -N xmlns="http://www.xyz.xx.xxx" -t -v "//xmlns:TReport/TModule/TItemGroup/Name" test-xml.xml

Any pointers appreciated...

test-xml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TReport xmlns="http://www.xyz.xx.xxx">
  <ProgVersion>1245219</ProgVersion>
  <BuildVersion>131923972</BuildVersion>
  <Completed>1</Completed>
  <TModule>
    <Capabilities>16519</Capabilities>
    <Name>Computer Overview</Name>
    <TypeID>5080</TypeID>
    <HelpID>5080</HelpID>
    <TItemGroup>
      <Name>ID</Name>
      <IconID>5656</IconID>
      <HelpID>0</HelpID>
      <TItem>
        <Name>Host Name</Name>
        <IconID>5080</IconID>
        <TypeID>0</TypeID>
        <DataValue>test2</DataValue>
        <HelpID>0</HelpID>
      </TItem>
      <TItem>
        <Name>Workgroup</Name>
        <IconID>5656</IconID>
        <TypeID>0</TypeID>
        <DataValue>WORKGROUP</DataValue>
        <HelpID>0</HelpID>
      </TItem>
    </TItemGroup>
  </TModule>
</TReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a default namespace in the XPath expression that xmlstarlet processes so you have to repeat your namespace prefix for each element you mention:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -N xmlns="http://www.xyz.xx.xxx" -t -v "//xmlns:TReport/xmlns:TModule/xmlns:TItemGroup/xmlns:Name" /tmp/test.xml
```

(I'm using Unix syntax but I trust you understand how it would look in Windows.)

With the above, I get `ID` as the output.

I would also suggest not using `xmlns` as your prefix. It works but it looks funny.